# Keyword argument performance (python)

Tags: python, performance, keyword-argument

I am trying to optimise some python code, via testing (timing) various functions using timeit.

I have found that I am getting different speeds depending on whether a variable is a keyword argument or within the function.

That is:

```
def test_function(A = value()):
    #rest of function....
```

Is returning a different result than:

```
def test_function():
    A = value()
    #rest of function ...
```

I would have figured they would have very similar results - I am guessing I am not understanding / missing something here...

(doing a 10,000 loops for the tests too)

Comment: make sure you understand the moral of doing `value()`. If this is some random id generator, you will be in trouble. That one id will be forever default. So make sure your application is okay by calling value().

Comment: There's a [`fast_function`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/ceval.c#l4059) speed hack in CPython, for a positional-only call if the function object lacks default arguments or cellvars/freevars setup. Otherwise it uses [`PyEval_EvalCodeEx`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/ceval.c#l3013). My tests with 255 arguments show about a 5-7% performance boost for no defaults vs defaults. But more importantly, using 255 keyword arguments was about 12-13 times slower in either case, since it's so much more work to setup and evaluate a call with keywords.

Comment: That said, evaluating the code of most functions will completely dwarf the call overhead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keyword arguments are evaluated once at function definition time. So in your first example `value()` is called exactly once, no matter how often you call the test function. If `value()` is expensive-ish this explains the difference in runtime between the two versions.

Comment: Right, thanks - that is the something I was missing! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are discussions as to why this method isn't the best to determine efficacy of approaches, but if you use `dis` to inspect the bytecode of the functions, you can see that they are structured in different ways, namely that `t1` evaluates its default argument at the time it is defined, and therefore does not require it to be redefined on subsequent function calls:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def t1(A=1):
...   pass
>>> def t2():
....  A=1
>>> dis.dis(t1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(t2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Cheers - haven't come across the `dis` module before - looks very useful,

Comment: @djmac Definitely can come in handy sometimes. Good question by the way!

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason your two functions should be expected to do the same thing, let alone have the same performance characteristics.

```
def test_function(A = value()):
    #rest of function....
```

This function doesn't have a "keyword argument"; there's no such thing. It has an argument with a default value. Any parameter for any function (some recalcitrant built-ins aside) can be **passed** by keyword or by position, but arguments are not intrinsically "keyword arguments".

The only association between keyword arguments and default values is that when you have *multiple* arguments with default values, the only way to supply an explicit value to a later argument while accepting the default for an earlier one is to pass the later argument by keyword.

The huge difference between the two functions is that when you declare a default value for `A`, it's a default **value**, not some code that will regenerate the value each time if an explicit value isn't provided. When you say this:

```
def test_function(A = value()):
    #rest of function....
```

You're setting a default **value** for `A`. As in any other context, when you provide a complex expression where Python needs a value, Python will evaluate that expression and then use the resulting value. So when you set the default value for `A`, at function definition time, it gets set to whatever `value()` returns at that time. Then that one single value is the default value for `A`.

```
def test_function():
    A = value()
    #rest of function ...
```

In this function, `value()` is evaluated every time the function is called. So if `value()` is expensive, then this version will take much longer than the first version. But if `value()` returns an object which you later mutate, then the default-argument version will be always using the one single object, in whatever state it was in at the time the function was called, while the second version will be constructing a new `value` every time. Which version you use should be determined by the semantics you want your program to have.

Comment: Thanks for your considered response! I had no-idea. Cheers.

Comment: There most certainly is such a thing as a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments), even in Python 2, and in Python 3 there are keyword-*only* arguments.

Comment: @agf That tutorial you linked to discusses keyword arguments exactly as I view them. A function just has formal parameters (and an optional `**kwargs`, so I suppose you could argue that any *particular* names it listens to from `**kwargs` are "keyword parameters"). At call time arguments may be **passed** by position *or* by keyword; it's not a property of the function's formal parameter. It's true that I omitted mentioning `**kwargs` (or keyword only parameters in Python3) to simplify the message. The core point I was making is "keyword" has nothing to do with "default value".